# TypeError - Torch.Device RepeatedScalarContainer

Tags: python, pytorch, ml-agent

I keep getting the error `TypeError: new() received an invalid combination of arguments - got (google.protobuf.pyext._message.RepeatedScalarContainer, int)`.

I've printed the type of `device`, finding that it's of class `torch.device` and tested all of the relevant commands in a separate program. The relevant code is below and the error is below that. I'm using this along with Unity's ML-Agents. What could the problem be?

```
device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
print(type(device))

class Agent():
    """Interacts with and learns from the environment."""

    def __init__(self, state_size, action_size, random_seed):
        """Initialize an Agent object.

        Params
        ======
            state_size (int): dimension of each state
            action_size (int): dimension of each action
            random_seed (int): random seed
        """
        self.state_size = state_size
        self.action_size = action_size
        self.seed = random.seed(random_seed)

        # Actor Network (w/ Target Network)
        self.actor_local = Actor(state_size, action_size, random_seed).to(device)
        self.actor_target = Actor(state_size, action_size, random_seed).to(device)
        self.actor_optimizer = optim.Adam(self.actor_local.parameters(), lr=LR_ACTOR)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 87, in <module>
    agent_1 = Agent(state_size=48, action_size=action_size, random_seed=0)
  File "C:\Users\Tester\ml-agents\ml-agents\mlagents\trainers\ddpg\ddpg_agent.py", line 39, in __init__
    self.actor_local = Actor(state_size, action_size, random_seed).to(device)
  File "C:\Users\Tester\ml-agents\ml-agents\mlagents\trainers\ddpg\model.py", line 29, in __init__
    self.fc3 = nn.Linear(fc2_units, action_size)
  File "C:\Users\Tester\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\ml-agents\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\linear.py", line 51, in __init__
    self.weight = Parameter(torch.Tensor(out_features, in_features))
TypeError: new() received an invalid combination of arguments - got (google.protobuf.pyext._message.RepeatedScalarContainer, int), but expected one of:
 * (torch.device device)
 * (torch.Storage storage)
 * (Tensor other)
 * (tuple of ints size, torch.device device)
      didn't match because some of the arguments have invalid types: (e[31;1mgoogle.protobuf.pyext._message.RepeatedScalarContainere[0m, e[31;1minte[0m)
 * (object data, torch.device device)
      didn't match because some of the arguments have invalid types: (e[31;1mgoogle.protobuf.pyext._message.RepeatedScalarContainere[0m, e[31;1minte[0m)
```

Comment: Somewhere you're feeding a tensor object with a `google.protobuf.pyext._message.RepeatedScalarContainer` when it's expecting an int, as per the error message.